# MySQL get two rows from a table in one join

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables:

```
Trip
|  id  |   name  | 
__________________
|  2   |    X    |
|  3   |    Y    | 
|  4   |    Z    |  

Tourist
| id   |   name  |
__________________
|  1   |   John  |
|  2   |    Doe  |
|  3   |  Margot |
|  4   |  Sarah  |
|  5   |   Bill  |
|  6   |   Alan  |

Reservation
| trip_id  |  tourist_id |
_________________________
|    2     |      1     |
|    2     |      4     |
|    4     |      6     |
```

I want to join the tables in a way that will get all tourists under one trip name:

```
{
    "trip_name": X,
    "tourists": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": John
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": Sarah
        }
    ],
}, 
{
    "trip_name": Z,
    "tourists": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": Alan
        }
    ],
}
```

Is this possible in one query? or should i do multiple queries? Or should i just go with one query and then loop trough results and create the object the way i want it?

Comment: Why are you hiding Sarah's name?

Comment: @Strawberry missclick sorry :D

Comment: what's your problem  ... the query or the json  response ??'

Comment: the query, i know how to write simple joins but i'm curious if there is a way to get an object like this in one query cause otherways i have to join the rows and then loop trough to create the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'trip_name',
            NAME,
            'tourists',
        (SELECT
            JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                JSON_OBJECT(
                    'id',
                    tourist.id,
                    'name',
                    tourist.name
                )
            )
        FROM
            tourist,
            reservation
        WHERE
            reservation.tourist_id = tourist.id AND reservation.trip_id = trip.id
            )
        )
    )
FROM
    trip
```

DB-FIDDLE https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fbfCwrufpBLFRSYBmGaVjp/0

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for! :D Do you know how well/bad this will perform?

Comment: I don't really know how much bad it is, but because of subQuery guess that it has not good performance. It can be written better. I tried to use JOIN - which are better than subquery, but unfortunatelly I couldn't do it normally )